# 或(者)，或是 and 或者是 difference?

Tags: word-choice, vocabulary

What is the difference between those three words?  I've been trying to find the answer, but some says they are all the same, some that 或者 is more formal, and some (but i think that person was a cantonese native speaker) that 或是 is more formal.
I know that 或者 is used in statements (vs. 还是), the other two are also used in statements or can be used in questions, too?

So they all mean "or"? And if so, are some more/less formal?

Answer (score 0):

或者 = 也许, "maybe"; "perhaps"

或**是** = 或许；也许**是** = 或者**是**, "or"; **"one or the other"**

还是, nevertheless; still; **or**

还是 has broader uses, see https://www.zdic.net/hans/%E8%BF%98%E6%98%AF for more info.